# How can I view a cheatsheet/summary of a syntax construct of zsh in zsh itself?

Tags: command-line, zsh, documentation

I want something like the `doc` function in Clojure; I want to type `cheat for` and be shown some example usages of `for` in zsh. I don't mind installing an app for this, and I hope something like this has already been done?

Answer (score 0):

I found some answers, which are great, but I'd appreciate knowing more alternatives.

https://github.com/chubin/cheat.sh

https://github.com/chrisallenlane/cheat (Installable by `brew`)